# Google reCAPTCHA v2 ignores CSS alignment

Tags: javascript, php, css, alignment, recaptcha

I'm trying to align a Google reCAPTCHA v2 element to the right side of my page, but it seems to be ignoring my styling.

I have tried to use CSS, HTML, PHP, and JavaScript to move the element, but nothing has worked — the reCAPTCHA `div` still aligns itself to the left side of the page. My code is not throwing any errors.

Every time the page reloads, the `div` seems to align to the right for an instant, but when the page finishes loading, it becomes left-aligned again. It almost seems like it's hard coded to be left-aligned for my domain, specifically. Is this the case? What can I do to override the `div`'s default styling?

Here is what I've tried so far:

HTML:

```
<div id='html_element'></div>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit" async defer></script>
```

CSS:

```
.html_element {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Find out what makes it left-aligned first of all, using your browser dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

On the demo page: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo

I used CSS to try align it some other way than left:

It appears the div it is in, if you use `text-align: -webkit-center;` it moves to the center. Align left, right etc do nothing, but webkit-* does :)

Not sure if it helps, but hope it does.

[image]

Comment: Tried it. It didn't work. Added width: 100%; still didn't work.

Comment: Ah thats too bad :(  Must be some CSS someway, but not sure what .